# Stop auto formatting cells

Tags: excel, database

I have a database and the value for one column is "6-25" excel keeps changing it to "Jun-25" how do I stop this from happening?
I'm using excel 2013.
Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Change the column to Text before importing the data.

Comment: hey, already did but that doesnt help

Comment: It depends on how you import, but basically you need to format the column as text BEFORE the data is entered on the sheet.  If you are opening a csv or txt file then you must use the import wizard and set the column as text in the wizard.  If you are copying/Pasting then set the column as text and make sure you are using the target formatting.  If you are hand entering the value then you must make the column text before entering the value.

Comment: For the manual entry that Scott mentioned, place an apostrophe at the beginning of the cell - that turns it into text.  I use it all the time fixing ID's like 1234E112 which Excel automatically changes to scientific notation.

Ah, excel is SOOOOOOoooooooo helpful...... [NOT].

Comment: Is the source of the data a **database** or is it a text file of some kind?

Comment: It is data that i downloaded from the web for analysis purpose